# Can I apply write rule for anyone for updating a particular item inside the object stored in firebase rt database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I would like to add firebase database rule to allow anyone to increment the "count" inside the `message` object. Is it possible to do so? If so, how should I write the rule for updating the `count`? Thanks!

```
{
  "messages": {
    "message0": {
      "content": "Hello",
      "count": 5
    },
    "message1": {
      "content": "Goodbye",
      "count": 10
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

I tried below rule, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      "$message": {
        "count": {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": true,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The rule you shared allows everyone to write the `count`, but nothign else. What isn't working about it? It's most likely we can help if you show the code that doesn't work with these rules.

Comment: My big mistake, I only changed the rules in my local file. There is no issue at all after I updated on firebase side.

Comment: Well, now this is just my issue. Should I still keep this question or I need to delete it?